# Displaying dropdownlistfor from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, enumdropdownlistfor

What I'm trying to do--

I have two different database tables (CabinetI, AdminCabinetI). AdminCabinetI has populated data(Column name ItemID) that has to be displayed to users as a dropdownlist. Once users fill out other information, make selections from the dropdownlist and hit the submit button, that data goes to CabinetI.

When I add Dropdownlistfor, it starts throwing an error. I've tried a lot of different ways, but nothing worked. So at this point, I would like to show my code and see what I've done wrong.

This is my ViewModel --

```
public class MultipleViews
{
    public Note note { get; set; }

    public AdminCabinetI admincabinetI { get; set; }

    public CabinetI cabineti { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AdminCabinetI> SelectSerialsI { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Models (AdminCabinetI) and (CabinetI) --

```
public class AdminCabinetI
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter item title")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Item Serial number/ID")]
    public string ItemID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select cabinet status")]
    public string ItemStatus { get; set; }

    public string BA { get; set; }

    public string Printer { get; set; }
}

public class CabinetI
{
    [Key]
    public int CabinetNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CabinetName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one of cabinet serial numbers")]
    public string CabinetSerial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select cabinet status")]
    public string CabinetStatus { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type specify cabinet location")]
    public string CabinetLocation { get; set; }

}
```

And this is my View --

@model PreMode.ViewModels.MultipleViews

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" style="opacity: 0.6" value="I2" asp-for="cabineti.CabinetName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Department</label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="cabineti.Department">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="cabineti.UserName" placeholder="Please enter your name" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="cabineti.UserName"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Serial Number</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.admincabinetI, new SelectList(Model.admincabinetI.ItemID, "ItemID"), "Select Cabinet Serial #", new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="cabineti.CabinetStatus">
            <option value="In Use">In Use</option>
            <option value="Not In Use">Not In Use</option>
            <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
        </select>
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="cabineti.CabinetStatus"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="cabineti.CabinetLocation" placeholder="Please type current location of the cabinet" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="cabineti.CabinetLocation"></span>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/Cabinet/MainCabinetI">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my Controller--

```
    public IActionResult GetDropDown()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            using (var db = new DataMigration())
            {
                var CabinetSerialsI = db.AdminCabinetI.ToList();

                var viewModel = new MultipleViews
                {
                    SelectSerialsI = CabinetSerialsI
                };
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: when you step through the code, at which point does the null ref happen?

Comment: That @Html.DropDownListFor part highlights and gives me that error.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.admincabinetI, new SelectList(Model.admincabinetI.ItemID, "ItemID"), "Select Cabinet Serial #", new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: In that case, I would assume your objects are not fully set up correctly. Step through the code and inspect the object db after the line using (var db = new DataMigration()). make sure all the information you want is there, then if that looks good step through the next line and inspect the CabinetSerialsI object. and so on. reply again if you see something unusual.

Comment: Thank you, but is that Html.dropdownlistfor part correct? I'm not sure that Html helper part has an issue or not.

Comment: Your issue is that `SelectSerialsI ` is never set to a new version of that object. You have simply set it to `CabinetSerialsI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectList` doesn't have an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method that matches your intentions.  In HTML land a select element has both values and descriptions, similar to a KeyValuePair.  In your case both the key and value are the same.  To account for that, try:

```
SelectList(Model.admincabinetI.ItemID, "ItemID", "ItemID")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This fixed my issue. It was so easy... and this makes me feel so stupid. haha. I literally spent hours to figure this out. James also helped me with as well and I personally want to choose 2 answers but it doesn't allow me to.. Anyways, thank you so much guys!!

Comment: The error was pretty obtuse here, don't sweat it.  Remember you can upvote answers if they helped :)

Comment: Hmmmm, but if I just hit the submit button and the <span class = "text-danger"> alert shows. However, after that, even though I refresh the page, the dropdownlist only displays, "Select Cabinet Serial #". I have to go back and forth to see the populated dropdownlist. How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, if you want to pre-populate the dropdownlist on-page-load, you need a different overload method.  Hint: it's a 4th param.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what's going on with your controller because it looks like MVC Core which I'm not familiar with and so reluctant to make further comment there.  Have you set breakpoints to see if it's being used?  Is ModelState.IsValid ever being hit?  You might be best to start a new question.

Comment: Alright, I will play with it and figure it out! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the `MultipleViews` class and set the variables such as this

```
public MultipleViews()
{
    this.Note  = new Note();
    this.AdminCabinetI  = new AdminCabinetI ();
    this.CabinetI  = new CabinetI ();
    this.SelectSerialsI  = new List<AdminCabinetI>();
}
```

You had not declared the variables before you set their value.

Comment: Hi James, thank you so much! However, after setting the variables, I'm still getting that null ref ;(

Comment: Thank you so much James, your answer and Khyron's made this work!